# How do I check a Pandas Datetime column for missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, missing-data

I have to check some data from an instrument and have to make sure that there are no missing time intervals.
So for example I have a Dataframe like this:

[image]

I've tried to generate a new datetime Series with 
`pd.date_range('2020-02-17 10:29:25', periods=1440, freq='T')`
and tried to compare it. But i got stuck.

Comment: please dont post images of your data. paste it in your question

Comment: always put data as text so we  could use it.

Comment: you can create columns with shifted data from `Datetime` so you will have two values in one row and then you can substract them and see if result is bigger then 1 minut

Comment: Yep i see how poor of a choice a picture was. Sorry guys, next time with code!

Answer (score 2):

You can put `Datetime` in new column but shifted one row down so you will have two values in one row and you can substract them and check if result is bigger then 1 minute.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'Datetime': [
    '2020-02-17 10:29:25',
    '2020-02-17 10:30:25',
    '2020-02-17 10:31:25',
    '2020-02-17 10:45:25',    
    '2020-02-17 10:46:25',    
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df['DT2'] = df['Datetime'].shift(1)
df['diff'] = df['Datetime'] - df['DT2']

# all values

print(df)

# compare with 1 minut

print(df[df['diff'] > datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)])
```

Result

```
# all values

             Datetime                 DT2     diff
0 2020-02-17 10:29:25                 NaT      NaT
1 2020-02-17 10:30:25 2020-02-17 10:29:25 00:01:00
2 2020-02-17 10:31:25 2020-02-17 10:30:25 00:01:00
3 2020-02-17 10:45:25 2020-02-17 10:31:25 00:14:00
4 2020-02-17 10:46:25 2020-02-17 10:45:25 00:01:00

# compare with 1 minut

             Datetime                 DT2     diff
3 2020-02-17 10:45:25 2020-02-17 10:31:25 00:14:00
```

---

**EDIT:** see @luigigi answer for simpler version which uses

```
df[ df['Datetime'].diff() > pd.Timedelta('60s') ]
```

Comment: @luigigi thank you, it is very interensting version. I added information about your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a daterange and check what values are missing in the DataFrame column. Like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Datetime':[*pd.date_range('2020-02-17 10:29:25', periods=3, freq='T'), *pd.date_range('2020-02-17 10:49:25', periods=3, freq='T')]})
df
             Datetime
0 2020-02-17 10:29:25
1 2020-02-17 10:30:25
2 2020-02-17 10:31:25
3 2020-02-17 10:49:25
4 2020-02-17 10:50:25
5 2020-02-17 10:51:25

my_range = pd.date_range(start=df['Datetime'].min(), end=df['Datetime'].max(), freq='T')

my_range[~my_range.isin(df['Datetime'])]
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-17 10:32:25', '2020-02-17 10:33:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:34:25', '2020-02-17 10:35:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:36:25', '2020-02-17 10:37:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:38:25', '2020-02-17 10:39:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:40:25', '2020-02-17 10:41:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:42:25', '2020-02-17 10:43:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:44:25', '2020-02-17 10:45:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:46:25', '2020-02-17 10:47:25',
               '2020-02-17 10:48:25'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')
```

---

Or you could use this (inspired by @furas):

```
df_missing = df[df['Datetime'].diff()>pd.Timedelta('60s')]
df_missing['diff'] = df.diff()
df_missing

             Datetime     diff
3 2020-02-17 10:49:25 00:18:00
```

Comment: simpler version is very interesting (+1)

Comment: Both versions are very helpful for my understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that every row is -1min compared to the next one and then do something if it isn't.

```
for i in range(len(df.index)-1):
   if datetime.datetime.strptime(df.loc[i, 'DateTime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) != datetime.datetime.strptime(df.loc[i+1, 'DateTime'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1):
      print('Data missing')
```